# Alternative TLDs on Microsoft Azure

Tags: domains, top-level-domains, azure

As many of you are aware, Microsoft Azure now has a little "Buy Domains" feature.

The domain name search however, constantly suggests TLDs such as .co.uk, .org.uk, etc. It's funny because I neither live in the UK, nor are my web apps and services based in the UK.

Does anyone know if you can purchase domain names with other TLDs on Azure? I'm looking for .io in particular but there are plenty of others that may suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can only purchase a very limited set of domain extensions on Azure. .io and others simply isn't supported.